# react-player: Is there a way to change video resolution with custom controls?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video.js, react-player

I am working on a custom video player that streams videos from different sources (YouTube, Vimeo, etc.) using react-player, and it already has functioning controls that I set up like play/pause, volume/mute, progress bar, and full screen.

I am trying to add a gear button that has a popover which displays different resolutions to set the video to, but I cannot seem to find any video quality selection implementation for react-player anywhere online.

Is this kind of functionality possible with react-player at all, or should I choose a different
react video player like video.js?

Comment: Hey, did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

it seems there is a way using `getInternalPlayer('hls')` and `onLoad` event.
see this answer in github issue:

https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/issues/523#issuecomment-442652418

Answer (score 0):

Here is a component sample using an HLS video file (m3u8)

```
const player = useRef();

const onChangeBitrate = (event) => {
    const internalPlayer = player.current?.getInternalPlayer('hls');
    if (internalPlayer) {
        // currentLevel expect to receive an index of the levels array
        internalPlayer.currentLevel = event.target.value;
    }
}

return <div>
  <ReactPlayer ref={player} url={'https://....m3u8'} />

  Quality:
  <select onChange={onChangeBitrate}>
    {player.current?.getInternalPlayer('hls')?.levels.map(
      (level, id) => <option key={id} value={id}>
        {level.bitrate}
      </option>
    )}
  </select>
</div>;
```

Comment: can u show the full code of this..?

Comment: What part is missing to you ?

Answer (score -1):

No, Not in the documentation also of react-player but if you want to change the resolution you can use the **Shaka Player** it will help to change the resolution of the video.

Use the NPM library for Player : [React Shaka Player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shaka-player-react)

Can also check the demo : [Shaka Player Demo](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/#audiolang=en-GB;textlang=en-GB;uilang=en-GB;panel=HOME;build=uncompiled)

Shaka Player also supports almost all functionality like in React player. We can able to use MP4, 3gp, and encrypted videos like DASH and m3u8.