# react-player quality change for mp4 video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-player

I'm recently started working on an app, that plays mp4 videos using react-player. It is a custom video player and below is my code for rendering React player. I covered almost all other functionalities except video quality change.

```
<ReactPlayer
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          url="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
          muted={muted}
          playing={playing}
          controls={false}
          ref={playerRef}
          volume={volume}
          playbackRate={playBackRate}
          onProgress={handleProgress}
          config={{
            file: {
              attributes: {
                crossOrigin: "anonymous"
              }
            }
          }}
        />
```

I would like to change the video quality same as the playback rate.

> I went through this link, but I'm working on `mp4` videos.
> [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69798410/react-player-is-there-a-way-to-change-video-resolution-with-custom-controls)

#### Could anyone share any suggestions on how we can achieve the same in MP4 videos?

I noticed one callback **props** `onPlaybackQualityChange` in the documentation. But not sure it can be useful in this situation in any way.